# what does differ exactly in simple english?

Tags: pronouns, reference

Limiting definitions of war and conflict to statistical criteria also distorts our reading of the ‘health’ of the contemporary global system.
According to data provided by Swedish researchers, **the scale or intensity of conflict differs from that of war in the annual number of ‘battle-related deaths’**; 25 battle-related deaths per year, including civilian casualties, for political violence to be categorized as armed conflict, and 1,000 combatant and non-combatant battle-related deaths per year for political violence to be categorized as a war.

Comment: *that* refers to "the scale or intensity"; this may be inferred from the fact that both are followed by a modifying *of* phrase. "The scale or intensity of conflict differs from the scale or intensity of war ..."

Comment: If you want to alter your question you may do so by clicking the 'edit' link immediately beneath the tags.

Comment: what is the meaning of: "for political violence to be categorized as armed conflict". what he wants to say simply in this paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

This is very slovenly writing. It is not the data but the study which provides the categories, the categories are not clearly distinguished and one of them is given two different names, the distinguishing measure is unnecessarily stated twice, in slightly differing forms, and a semicolon is used where a colon is called for.

What the author means is something like this:

> A recent Swedish study categorizes the scale or intensity of political violence by the annual number of combatant and non-combatant battle-related deaths: an episode which results in 25 such deaths in a year is categorized as "armed conflict", and one which results in 1,000 is categorized as a "war".